# Plotting with pandas and matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe, scatter-plot

I'm trying to create a scatter plot in Python. I have a dataframe 'df' with a specified category and x and y are column numbers:

```
groups = df.groupby(category)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for name, group in groups:
    ax.plot(x=group.iloc[:,x], y=group.iloc[:,y], marker='o', linestyle='',label=name)
fig = ax.get_figure()
fig.savefig(path)
```

For some reason, I am getting an empty scatterplot -- Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ax.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot.html) does not have `x` and `y` arguments.

The signature is `Axes.plot(*args, **kwargs)`, meaning that `x` and `y` are simply positional arguments. If you specify `x=` and `y=` they will be treated as keyword arguments and ignored.

So remove `x=` and `y=` from the code,

```
ax.plot(group.iloc[:,x], group.iloc[:,y], marker='o', linestyle='',label=name)
```

Complete example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({"x":np.random.rand(40), 
                   "y":np.random.rand(40),
                   "category": np.random.choice(list("ABCD"), size=40)})
category = "category"
x=1; y=2
groups = df.groupby(category)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for name, group in groups:
    ax.plot(group.iloc[:,x], group.iloc[:,y], marker='o', linestyle='',label=name)
fig = ax.get_figure()
#fig.savefig(path)
plt.show()
```